# firebase real-time database rules for admin sdk

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, authorization, firebase-admin

How can apply real-time database rules on firebase admin sdk for REST API.

```
{ 
 "rules": {
   "users": {
     ".read": auth != null,
     ".write": auth != null
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Youn can't. The [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) is just that - an SDK with administrative privileges. You might consider using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) or the [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) instead.

Comment: @Grimthorr is correct.  I just wanted to add that I'll use this property to my advantage by setting branches to `write : false, read : false` for admin only branches, `write : auth != null, read : false` for write-only branches (submission queue) and `write : false, read : auth != null` for read-only branch (published).

Answer (score 0):

You can authorize Admin SDK with limited privileges by setting the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` option. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges for details.